# What's the benefit of using format operators over the variable itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Fairly simple question - in what situations would you prefer to use format operators over the variable itself? Are they just for code readability, or are there other legitimate uses for them?

```
name = str(input("Hello! What is your name? "))
age = int(input("How old are you?"))

output = "%s is %d years old." % (name, age)
print(output)
```

VS

```
name = str(input("Hello! What is your name? "))
age = int(input("How old are you?"))

output = name, "is", age, "years old."
print(output)
```

Comment: Format operators useful for floating point numbers, adding zeros to the beginning or left/right padding.

Comment: your two examples are not equivalent at all. `output` in your second example is a *tuple*, and it is a string in your first. Have you actually checked the outputs? Anyway, old-style `%` formatting is pretty much deprecated, you should use the `.format` or even f-strings in python 3.6

Comment: Your second example is a **tuple**, not a string, and your output will differ **hugely**. You could get the same with `print(*output)` perhaps, but string formatting can do **far, far more** than just convert values to strings.

Comment: Try to add column widths, and then alignment, for example. Or zero-padding to the numbers. Then make the alignment or column width variable. Then mix in custom types that need to support different formatting operations. String formatting (with `str.format()` specifically) is far more powerful than just outputting a few values in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use string interpolation

```
"%s is %d years old" % (name, age)        # old and busted
```

but should instead use either `str.format`

```
"{} is {:d} years old".format(name, age)  # modern
```

or f-strings in Python 3.6+

```
f"{name} is {age} years old"              # new hotness
```

Your examples are not equivalent, but even if they were it's showcasing only the most basic features of string formatting -- putting variables in the middle of a string. Instead let's look at more intermediate features, like padding:

```
headers = ["some", "words", "that", "are", "headers", "to", "a", "table"]
```

let's imagine we want equal-size columns, so we can't just do:

```
' '.join(headers)  # "some words that are headers to a table"
                   #  ^--- not equal-size columns!
```

but must instead format each string

```
common_width = max(map(len, headers))
result = ' '.join(["{h:<{width}}".format(h=h, width=common_width) for h in headers])
# "some    words   that    are     headers to      a       table"
#  ^--- equal-size columns!
```

Or maybe you want to calculate an average that you want to be exact, but only want it to be displayed to two decimal places.

```
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sum_ = sum(data)
length = len(data)
avg = sum_ / length * 100

print("Average is " + str(avg) + "%")
# "Average is 63.63636363636363%"
print("Average is {:.02f}%".format(avg))
# "Average is 63.64%"  <-- clearly easier to read!
# equivalently: f"Average is {avg:.02f}%"
```

Comment: In your `str.format()` example, at least use the `:d` format specifier if you are going to make it equivalent to the printf-style template.